# generate random number with a specific sum

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

How do I generate `8` random numbers from `1` to `100` The sum of `8` numbers is `200` Not Without repeating the same numbers in each group Showing all possible outcomes.

Comment: This question is not specific to c#, it’s algorithmic. I think you'd have a better chance of answer asking on Leetcode or Hackerrank.

Comment: What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: `Not without repeating` so they can repeat? (double negative)

Comment: Since you are saying `Showing all possible outcomes` I don’t really see the point of the randomness.

Comment: As a start, generate 7 random numbers. If total is less than 200,the 8th number is the rest. Else try again

Comment: If the goal is to generate possible combinations, evenly sampling out of all the ways to do it, you need to use dynamic programming to figure out the odds of each number being chosen and then select it that way.  Lots of my answers have shown the technique.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what *random* means here. You can, for instance, put a problem like this:

> There is a stick of length `200`
> We should put `8 - 1 = 7` random marks on it to cut stick into `8` pieces and return the *lengths* of these pieces.

Let's draw a pictute:

```
[----------------------------------------------------------]
^     ^     ^      ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^ 
0    33    83     135     138     157     177     186     200 <- points

  33    50     52      3      19      20       9       14     <- lengths
```

**Code:**

```
Random random = new Random();

...

int length = 200;
int count = 8;
int prior = 0;

int[] values = Enumerable
  .Range(0, count - 1)
  .Select(_ => random.Next(0, length + 1))
  .OrderBy(item => item)
  .Append(length)
  .Select(item => {
     int savedPrior = prior;

     prior = item;

     return item - savedPrior; })
  .ToArray();
```

If you want all `values` being *distinct* or you want to impose another condition (say, all values should be less then `100`) you can try repeating the procedure when they are not:

```
int[] values;
int length = 200;
int count = 8;

do {
  int prior = 0;

  values = Enumerable
    .Range(0, count - 1)
    .Select(_ => random.Next(0, length + 1))
    .OrderBy(item => item)
    .Append(length)
    .Select(item => {
       int savedPrior = prior;

        prior = item;

        return item - savedPrior; })
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();
}
while (values.Length != count || values.Any(item => item >= 100));
```